# Prove $\forall a,b\in \mathrm{Z^{even}},$ if $a\not\equiv b (\mod 3)$ then $\frac{b-a}{2}\equiv 1 (\mod3)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Prove $\forall a,b\in \mathrm{Z^{even}},$ if $a\not\equiv b (\mod 3)$ then $\frac{b-a}{2}\equiv 1 (\mod3)$

I think my above proof is wrong, I proceed to try some values, like

$2 \mod 3 = 2$,

$4 \mod 3 = 1$

$-2 \mod 3 = 1$,

$-4 \mod 3 = 2$

So if I let $a = -2$ and $b = 2$, $-2\not\equiv 2 (\mod 3)$ but $\frac{2-(-2)}{2} = 2\not\equiv 1 (\mod3)$. Is this a counter example to this question? So hence I just disprove this statement?

Comment: What does this mean $Z^{even}$. Is it the same as this $Z^2$

Comment: Yes, of course , That can be refuted .

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Use `$a\equiv b\pmod{n}$` for $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$.

Comment: The line "since $a$, $b$ are even they have remainder $0$ or $2$ after division by three" is incorrect. For example, $4$ is even but $4 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: $\bmod 3\!:\ 2\equiv-1\Rightarrow n/2\equiv -n,\,$ so your claim is $\,a\not\equiv b\Rightarrow a-b\equiv 1,\,$ clearly false (e.g. $\,a=4,b=2)\,$ Checking your proof line-by-line with this counterexmaple shows your first claim (2nd line) is already false, i.e. $\,4\not\equiv 0,2\pmod{3}.\,$ This is a general method of debugging proofs - see the linked dupe.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: @JackDavidson Yes I understand, it can also be 4 mod 3 is 1, the written proof is wrong. What about my counter example? Is that a valid counter example to disprove the statement? Thanks.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes I apologise I knew that line 2 was incorrect, as 1 could also be the result of (mod 3), which is why I wrote down a counter example, If my counter example valid?

Comment: @SarahV.P Yep! Finding a counterexample is always a valid way to disprove a statement.

Comment: @JackDavidson Is mine valid? Like picking $a = -2$ and $b = 2? $ Did I disproved it?

Comment: @SarahV.P Yes it is, since $\frac{2-(-2)}{2}=2 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Let $\,a,b = 2j,2k.$ $\!\bmod 3\!:\ \overbrace{2j\not\equiv 2k}^{\large a\ \not\equiv\ b}\!\iff\! j\not \equiv k$ 
 which *doesn't* imply $\!\!\overbrace{k\!-\!j}^{\large (b-a)/2 }\!\!\!\equiv 1$ (e.g. $\,k\!=\!2,j\!=\!0)$

Comment: @BillDubuque What do you mean?

Comment: My prior comment shows how to deduce that the  claim in the title is false.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Let $E$ be the set of even numbers. Then, if $(a, b) \in E$, we have $a = 2k, b = 2m, (k, m) \in \mathbf{Z}$ and we have $\frac{b-a}{2} = m - k$. Now, $\neg \ a \equiv b  \ (\mod3) \iff \neg \ m \equiv k \ (\mod 3)$. Now, if for example $m \equiv 0 (\mod 3), k \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$, we have $m - k = -1 \equiv 2 (\mod 3)$, which shows that your proof is flawed. A big mistake I can see in your proof is assuming that $k$ and $m$ are either $0$ or $2$, they can be $1$ as well, as in $m = 3l + 1 (l \in \mathbf{Z})$...

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Thanks Martin, yes I understand that my proof is wrong, but what about the "counter example" that I provided? Is that valid to disprove the question? Thanks.

Comment: @SarahV.P yes, finding a counter example is always a valid way of disproving a conjecture!

Comment: @MartinWestin Is mine valid? Like picking $a = -2$ and $b = 2? $ Did I disproved it?

Comment: @SarahV.P Yes absolutely